# Can use of 'eigen' library in C++ beat matlab in big matrix manipulations?

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, eigen

I made a simple matrix multiplication program, with two matrices 50000x50000 and multiplied them. I did this in C++ using library eigen and matlab. However execution time in matlab was lower than using eigen. While using eigen, I left all compiling (and maybe running) options to default.

I know matlab is built as a vecorized program and it can take help of multi-processors and parallelization. However if I want to develop programs with large matrices and linear algebra, is it possible to will use of eigen library beat matlab's performance? Or one has to go to proprietary Intel (or others) libraries? And any comments how we can do this?

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea to close the question, as many of us are working on numerical simulations

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely hard to beat `MATLAB`, even with all optimizations turned on. To get the most out of `Eigen` you need to compile with parallel support (`-fopenmp` in `gcc`), and turn optimizations on (`-O3`). Even in this case, `MATLAB` will be slightly faster, mainly because it is using the Intel MKL  proprietary library to get the most out of Intel chips, so unless you buy it I don't think you will be able to beat it. I am currently using `Eigen` for a project and wasn't able to beat `MATLAB` (at least not for dense matrix multiplication).

For example, for `A*B` where `A` and `B` are `1000 x 1000` the best average time I can get is:

`MATLAB`: 0.32 seconds
`Eigen`: 0.44 seconds

For `2000 x 2000`,

`MATLAB`: 2.80 seconds
`Eigen`: 3.45 seconds

System: MacbookPro 2013, OS X.

PS: I highly doubt you will be able to multiply `50000x50000` matrices (at least on ordinary computers) because you will be out of RAM.

Comment: Well, one can install the required 28+ GiB of RAM on today's desktop motherboards (~9.3 GiB for `A`, `B` and `A*B`), so depends on what you understand by "ordinary computers" :) . Even if you don't have so much RAM, you can have fairly fast SSDs, which when used as swap will still make the computation not too long.